# Density of "Fibonacci friends"

Tags: nt.number-theory, measure-theory, fibonacci-numbers

Let $F$ be the set of all integers $n>1$ such that in the [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence) modulo $n$, the value $0$ occurs infinitely often. What is the value of $\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\frac{|F\cap\{0,\ldots,n\}|}{n+1}$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The value $0$ always occurs infinitely often regardless of the value $n>1$. To see this, consider the mapping $L_n:\mathbb{Z}_n^2\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_n^2$ defined by $L_n(x,y)=(y,x+y)$. Then the mapping $L_n$ is invertible. Then if we set $F_{0,n}=[0]_n,F_{1,n}=[1]_n$ and $F_{i+2,n}=F_{i+1,n}+F_{i,n}$, then $F_{i,n}$ is the $i$-th Fibonacci number modulo $n$. On the other hand,
$L_n(F_{i,n},F_{i+1,n})=(F_{i+1,n},F_{i+2,n})$, so $L_n^m(F_{i,n},F_{i+1,n})=(F_{i+m,n},F_{i+m+1,n})$ for all $m\geq 0$. Since $L_n$ is invertible, there must be some $m>0$ where $([0]_n,[1]_n)=L^m_n([0]_n,[1]_n)=L^m_n(F_{0,n},F_{1,n})=(F_{m,n},F_{m+1,n})$, so $F_{m,n}=[0]_n$.

This is in contrast to the Foobonacci sequence where the function $M_n$ is not injective. Define the Foobonacci sequence $FO_{1,n}=1,FO_{2,n}=1,FO_{i+2,n}=FO_{i+1,n}*_nFO_{i,n}$ where $*_n$ is the self-distributive operation in the $n$-th Laver table. For example, in Hexadecimal ($104_{\text{hex}}=260_{\text{dec}}$), we have (according to my artificial intelligence calculations but without proof) $(FO_{1,104},\dots,FO_{7,104})=(1,1,2,3, F00...008, \mathbf{F00...00B}, 100...00)$, so we call this sequence the Foobonacci sequence.

The mapping
$M_n:A_n^2\rightarrow A_n^2$ defined by $M_n(x,y)=(x*_ny,x)$ (where $A_n$ denotes the $n$-th Laver table) is not invertible, and for all $n>1$, there is no $t>2$ where $FO_{n,t}=1$, but for all $n>1$, we eventually have
$FO_{n,2t+1}=2^n$ for sufficiently large $t$.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period for more information about the actual (smallest) value of $m$ as a function of $n$, i.e., the order of $L_n$ as an element of $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}_n)$.

Comment: @bof. I just could not resist using the phrase 'Foobonacci sequence'.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450200/density-of-fibonacci-friends#comment1163776_450201), I think part of the fun of working with Fibonacci numbers is coming up with silly names.  Paul Sally liked to talk about numbers satisfying the recurrence $T(n + 3) = T(n + 2) + T(n + 1) + T(n)$, I forget with what initial condition, and called them, of course, Tribonacci numbers.

Comment: A slick way to see that infinitely Fibonacci numbers are divisible by $n$ is the following: we can run the Fibonacci recurrence backward to define $F_k$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Clearly the Fibonacci number modulo $n$ are periodic since there are only finitely many values of $(F_i,F_{i+1})$ mod $n$. But $F_0=0$.